# "Could not lookup Ecto repo" error during tests

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've been getting the following exception when trying to setup a new ecto repo. Currently only using it for testing (since i am just setting this up).

`** (RuntimeError) could not lookup Ecto repo Lipwig.AnnotatedUnit.Repo because it was not started or it does not exist`

This happens when my tests use `Lipwig.AnnotatedUnit.DataCase`. However, when i use `Lipwig.DataCase` (which references the Lipwig.Repo`), the tests run fine.

I have the following setup in the project.

```
defmodule Lipwig.Repo do
  use Ecto.Repo,
    otp_app: :lipwig,
    adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres
end

defmodule Lipwig.AnnotatedUnit.Repo do
  use Ecto.Repo,
    otp_app: :lipwig,
    adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres
end
```

This here is my test setup

```
defmodule Lipwig.DataCase do
  use ExUnit.CaseTemplate

  using do
    quote do
      alias Lipwig.Repo

      import Ecto
      import Ecto.Changeset
      import Ecto.Query
      import Lipwig.DataCase
    end
  end

  setup tags do
    :ok = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.checkout(Lipwig.Repo)

    unless tags[:async] do
      Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.mode(Lipwig.Repo, {:shared, self()})
    end

    :ok
  end

  def errors_on(changeset) do
    Ecto.Changeset.traverse_errors(changeset, fn {message, opts} ->
      Regex.replace(~r"%{(\w+)}", message, fn _, key ->
        opts |> Keyword.get(String.to_existing_atom(key), key) |> to_string()
      end)
    end)
  end
end

defmodule Lipwig.AnnotatedUnit.DataCase do
  use ExUnit.CaseTemplate

  using do
    quote do
      alias Lipwig.AnnotatedUnit.Repo

      import Ecto
      import Ecto.Changeset
      import Ecto.Query
      import Lipwig.AnnotatedUnit.DataCase
    end
  end

  setup tags do
    :ok = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.checkout(Lipwig.AnnotatedUnit.Repo)

    unless tags[:async] do
      Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.mode(Lipwig.AnnotatedUnit.Repo, {:shared, self()})
    end

    :ok
  end

  def errors_on(changeset) do
    Ecto.Changeset.traverse_errors(changeset, fn {message, opts} ->
      Regex.replace(~r"%{(\w+)}", message, fn _, key ->
        opts |> Keyword.get(String.to_existing_atom(key), key) |> to_string()
      end)
    end)
  end
end
```

My other datacase for `Lipwig.Repo` is almost identical, just referencing the other repo.

My `config.exs` config defines

```
config :lipwig,
  ecto_repos: [Lipwig.Repo, Lipwig.AnnotatedUnit.Repo]
```

My `test.exs` config is

```
config :lipwig, Lipwig.Repo,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  database: "lipwig_test",
  hostname: "localhost",
  pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox

config :lipwig, Lipwig.AnnotatedUnit.Repo,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  database: "lipwig_test",
  hostname: "localhost",
  pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox
```

Comment: I believe you left out the code for `Lipwig.DataCase` -- what differences are there between it and `Lipwig.AnnotatedUnit.DataCase`?
Also, which repos are you starting in your app's config via the `ecto_repos: [Some.Repo]` key?

Comment: I added those explicitly then. ecto_repos has both. And as described, Both datacases are almost identical, i literary copypasted and then just replaced the repo names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my knowledge, the configurations seem fine. As the error suggests, I think the issue might be because you are not starting the `Lipwig.AnnotatedUnit.Repo` in with you application.

Look for the `application.ex` file in the `/lib/lipwig_web` folder and make sure that `Lipwig.AnnotatedUnit.Repo` is added in the children array.

Hope this resolves

Comment: Thanks. It was missing in the application.